# QuickBooks Create Jobs QBFC

Tags: quickbooks

Does anyone know if there is a way to add customer Jobs through QuickBooks desktop SDK? I see that I can add Customer and as part of that I can specify the Job info but that endpoint doesn't have other job info that goes with Job creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jobs` in QuickBooks are just `Customers` with a parent customer. e.g. Customers and Jobs are *the same thing* except that Jobs belong to a Customer.

So, create a `Job` exactly how you'd create a `Customer`, except make sure you set these fields:

`ParentRef/ListID`

Or

`ParentRef/FullName`

Which attach the job to a specific customer.

Comment: Thanks Keith. What about adding additional info and custom fields info for the job? I don't see any option to do that.

Comment: Specifically WHAT additional information are you trying to add? If you search StackOverflow for "quickbooks custom fields" you'll find plenty of posts about how to set custom fields on customers/jobs.

Comment: I want to add information in "Additional Info" tab when creating a job. There are also custom fields.

Comment: OK, that's all documented in the QuickBooks OSR. What's the issue?